# EF6 + SQLite + Code First Out of Memory exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, code-first

I use `Entity framework 6` and `SQLite` + `Code First`
And I get `Out of Memory exception` in following code, though I am freeing all memory.

If I uncomment the next line does not show any error.

`System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("");`

Does anyone have an explanation for this?
Are COM communication to SQLITE depends on Wimdows Messages?

```
using SQLite.CodeFirst;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace SQLiteDemo
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Node> list = new List<Node>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 700000; ++i)
            {
                list.Add(new Node() { Id = i, Name = i.ToString() });
            }
            AddListToTree(list);
        }

        private void AddListToTree(List<Node> list)
        {
            TreeDbContext db = new TreeDbContext();
            db.Tree.Load();

            var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction();
            int Counter = 0;

            foreach (var node in list)
            {
                Counter += 1;
                if (Counter % 100000 == 0)
                {
                    // the magic here 
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("");
                }
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO [Nodes]([Name], [Order], [Type], [Parent_Id]) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3);",
                    node.Name, node.Order,
                    node.Type,
                    node.Parent == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : node.Parent.Id);
            }
            transaction.Commit();
            transaction.Dispose();
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }

    class Node
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Node Parent { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public byte Type { get; set; }
    }

    class TreeDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public TreeDbContext()
            : base("MyDbContextDB")
        { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var sqliteConnectionInitializer = new SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TreeDbContext>(modelBuilder);
            Database.SetInitializer(sqliteConnectionInitializer);
        }

        public DbSet<Node> Tree { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `.Load()`? Why even use a `DbContext` here if all you are doing is executing ado.net statements? Why create a new DbContext instance every `100000` records, because you are using ado.net nothing is tracked to begin with. If you really want to know why you get the OOME you will have to profile the application's memory which can be done using a profile tool or Visual Studio if you are using Ultimate/Enterprise edition.

Comment: Can you explain why OOME appears only if I do not  calling `MessageBox.Show`?

Comment: Not according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.load(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: Remove line 

GC.Collect();

when it will be ready GC frees memory.

Comment: @sglogowski @Igor, I edited the question, please explain why OOME appears only if I do not calling `MessageBox.Show`?

Comment: It sounds like there is some code inside the ExecuteSqlCommand that does not dispose properly. The garbage collect will collect garbage when there is time, but without the message box you have a tight loop and there is never any time. So, I would probably start verifying the code for SQLite EF. I'm assuming the bug is not the EF6 itself. The bug does not seem to be in your code. You might want to verify this with a console application so you don't have any complications with the other parts of your app.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently face with a similar exception and googling it got me to this question.

For anyone that would end-up on this page thanks to google, I thought I would provide my solution.

So I was trying to map a raw sql query to an object and got a "Out Of Memory exception" which I did not understand because I had 3 entities to map...

It turns out that when you're mapping a raw sql result to an object with something like :

```cs
context.Database.SqlQuery<MyObject>($"SQL QUERY").ToList()
```

The property of `MyObject` are to be the same as the result of the query (no more no less). Failing to do so will mess with the inner mapping of SQLite3 driver which leads it to request a column with the index `-1` to the statement handler, which will be seen by the driver as a bad memory allocation which will trigger the OOME.